# MS SQL Linked Server

Tags: sql-server

Подскажите, есть ли возможность внести изменения в параметр @datasrc свойства Linked Server'a через графический интерфейс студии? Cвязанный сервер создавался запросом, который сейчас утерян. В обозревателе объектов в свойствах Linked Servera такой возможности не вижу.

Comment: Properties/general/data source не пробовали?

Comment: @АмирЗакиров, там можно только просмотреть св-ва соединения, этого параметра там нет (да и всё read only)

Comment: Тогда можно сгенерировать скрипт и пересоздать его с нужным параметром. Пробовали?

Comment: @АмирЗакиров , спасибо за совет! Думал об этом, но боюсь, как бы что не испортилось при пересоздании. Поэтому и хотел просто поправить нужный параметр (уверен, что ошибка именно в нем)